# Disable My Account and show after login in Magento2

Tags: magento2

Help me please . Disable My Account and show after login in Magento2.
i want to change top.link in magento2 .  it have [ My Account , My wish list , Create account  and sign in  ] but  i want hide btn {My Account}  and show it after customer login success. I see block and template  in Module Customer  but not understand. Please help me Plugin , override ,create block or something .

Comment: You mean you can not login to admin? your admin user is locked? can't you explain a bit more?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in your question?

Comment: i want to change top.link in magento2 .  it have [ My Account , My wish list , Create account  and sign in  ] but  i want hide btn {My Account}  and show it after customer login success. I see block and template  in Module Customer  but not understand. Please help me Plugin , override ,create block or something .